# Javascript: JSON request works only for the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a script which registers a click event to a button.
The function which should be executed when the button is clicked, should make a JSON request to a Quotes API and give my Quote element the random quote.

```
  $("document").ready(function() {
  $("#new-quote").on("click", newQuote());
});

function newQuote() {
  $.getJSON("http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&callback=", function(a) {
    $("#quote-paragraph").html(a[0].content);
    $("#footer").html(a[0].title);
  });
}
```

This is how my code should look like, but I already tried different solutions and to find my error. I added an alert() statement at the end of my function to see if the function gets executed, which it does. Well sometimes. I tried it a couple times and got different results each time I tried it. I am working with codepen.io . Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the second line

```
$("#new-quote").on("click", newQuote());
```

You're executing the function and assigning its result to the onclick event instead of assigning the function itself. That's why your function executes once, when you do the assignment, and not again, because you didn't actually assign it. Do this:

```
$("#new-quote").on("click", newQuote);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it and it executes the function now. The problem now is that it does not do the JSON request anymore. I can see that it executes the function because I added alert() and it gives me an alert, but no change in my quote.

Comment: Could you update the code and include the html markup so we have more info? Maybe post a link to the codepen or create a fiddle

Comment: Ok. I used a new API now and everything is working fine. Thank you a lot.

Comment: Just to let you know it's probably because codepen cached the request. IE does this as well. Adding a random number to the end of the url fixes it.

http://codepen.io/jgodson/pen/kXJXKa